# ActiveRecord. Find all records by attribute the values of which are included in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to create a scope on my `User` model that would get all the users whose email attribute is included into the `AdminUser` model's emails.

Basically, there's an attribute called `email` in the `User` model and the same attribute in the `AdminUser` model. So, I need to get all the users which are actually admins (by emails).

I didn't succeed in implementing this as a signle query and started with getting the array  of `AdminUser` emails:

```
emails = AdminUser.pluck(:email)
```

and now I'm struggling with getting the array of admin users from `User` model.

If I write something like this:

```
User.find_by_email(emails)
```

I get just one entity, not the array.

---

So, my question:

How can I create a scope, say `admins`, on the `User` model that would return the array of admins?

---

BTW: for some other purposes I have this method in my `User`:

```
  def admin?
    AdminUser.find_by(email: email) ? true : false
  end
```

so, maybe I could somehow make use of it in this case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you pass an array to the value of an attribute in a where clause, it'll do what you want.

```
@user = User.where(email: AdminUser.pluck(:email))
```

Comment: really? that simple? so cooool

Comment: Didn't think of this. Good one :)

Answer (score 8):

The finder methods returns a single record always. You can use `where`

```
User.where(email: emails)
```